# WinJS.xhr Timeout Loses Requests?

Tags: timeout, xmlhttprequest, winjs

What I'm trying to do (though [I fully suspect there's a *better* way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14041621/328193) to do it) is to send HTTP requests to a range of hosts on my network.  I can hit every host by calling `WinJS.xhr` in a loop.  However, it takes too long to complete the range.

Inspecting in Fiddler shows that a dozen or so requests are sent at a time, wait to time out, and then move on to the next dozen or so.  So I figured I'd try to reduce the timeout for each request.  For my needs, if the host doesn't respond in 500 ms, it's not going to respond.

Following [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868283.aspx), I tried wrapping the call to `WinJS.xhr` in a call to `WinJS.Promise.timeout` with a small enough setting, but there was no change.  Changing the promise timeout didn't really affect the actual request.

A little more searching led me to [a suggestion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/db7ccb75-57d0-40e5-973a-b52b217653af) whereby I could modify the `XMLHttpRequest` object that `WinJS.xhr` uses and set the timeout on that.  This worked like a charm in terms of blasting out requests at a faster rate.  However, there seems to be a side-effect.

Watching the requests in Fiddler, about a dozen or so fire off very quickly and then the whole thing ends.  The "next dozen or so" never come.  *Sometimes* (based on the semi-randomness of asynchronous calls) the first dozen or so that shows up in fiddler includes 9-10 from the low and of the range and 2-3 from the top end of the range, or close to it.

Is there something else I can try, or some other way to accomplish the end goal here?  (Within the scope of this question the end goal is to send a large number of requests in a reasonable amount of time, but any suggestions on a better overall way to scan for a particular service on a network is also welcome.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you write out the code you're using for timeout, i wrote something like this but it wasn't working, so I'm curious as to how you're doing it:

```
    var timeoutFired = function () {
        console.log("derp");
    };

    var options = {
        url: "http://somesite.com",
        responseType: "document",
        customRequestInitializer: function (req) {
            req.timeout = 1;
            req.ontimeout = timeoutFired;
            //do something with the XmlHttpRequest object req
         }
    };

    WinJS.xhr(options).
    ....
```

Here are some alternatives that you may find helpful,  not sure how/why timeout wasn't working but I tried to write out a custom timeout function:

```
(function (global) {
    var options = {
        url: "http://something.com",
        responseType: "document",
    };

    var request = WinJS.xhr(options).then(
        function (xmlHttpRequest) {
            console.log("completed");
        },
        function (xmlHttpRequest) {
            //error or cancel() will throw err
            console.log("error"+ xmlHttpRequest.message);

        },
        function (xmlHttpRequest) {
            console.log("progress")
    });  

    function waitTime() {
        return new WinJS.Promise(
            function (complete, error, progress) {
                var seconds = 0;
                var interval = window.setInterval(
                    function () {
                        seconds++;
                        progress(seconds);
                        //prob should be called milliseconds
                        if (seconds > 5) {
                            window.clearInterval(interval);
                            complete();
                        }
                    }, 100);
            });
    };

    waitTime().done(
        function () {
            console.log("complete");
            request.cancel();
        },
        function () {
            console.log("error")
        },
        function (seconds) {
            console.log("progress:" + seconds)
        });
});
```

Another cool little trick is using promise.any (vs .join) which fires off when one OR the other finishes first, so taking that into account you can write something like this:

```
 (function (global) {
    var options = {
        url: "http://url.com",
        responseType: "document",
    };

    var request = {
        runRequest: function () {
            return WinJS.xhr(options).then(
            function (xmlHttpRequest) {
                console.log("completed");
            },
            function (xmlHttpRequest) {
                //error or cancel() will throw err
                console.log("error" + xmlHttpRequest.message);

            },
            function (xmlHttpRequest) {
                console.log("progress")
            });
        }
    };

    WinJS.Promise.any([WinJS.Promise.timeout(500), request.runRequest()]).done(
        function () {
            console.log("any complete");
        });
})();
```